# update/modify svg img tag from php file

Tags: php, jquery, svg

I have SVG version of USA map, and wanted to modify each state there, however, the SVG file was attribute to `img` tag.

**Code Fig. 1:**

```
<img src="https://www.domain.com/path/to/svg/usa-map.svg" alt="">
```

Each State (svg path) from `usa-map.svg` will need to update from the admin, where it should be highlighted from the output where if the State (svg path) have property location. *Shown in Example.*

**Image Fig. 1:**
[image]

> Note: Dark colored States have property locations

**Case:**

Previously in our code, we've managed to use direct SVG in our code and update the State (svg path) via admin using jQuery css to highlight certain State (svg path).

**Code Fig. 2:**

```
<script>$("{{$california_state}}").css({ fill: "#9DC75B" });</script>
```

We decide to use the img tag instead of full raw svg element to reduce weight of the file and speed-up the SEO performance.

**Question:**

Is it possible to update/modify the SVG path (while it was viewable in `img` tag) via internal PHP file where this internal file calling the SVG element and inject the css to highlight certain states using jQuery script using our method or is there better alternative solutions for this?

Comment: img tags don't run script.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using webserver rewrites to an svg file path wich originally is an php file that opens the real svg and modifies it could be an solution.

So you could still include the image over an img tag.